# passwords with special characters lead to an error in "toad for mysql"

Tags: mysql, toad

My MySQL account has a password with the special char `"` in it. If I try to connect to the MySQL server with Toad for MySQL, it leads to following the error (I only got it in german):

> System.ArgumentException Das Format der Initialisierungszeichenfolge
>   stimmt nicht mit der Spezifikation überein, die bei Index '19'
>   beginnt. Stack Trace:    bei
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.GetKeyValuePair(String
>   connectionString, Int32 currentPosition, StringBuilder buffer, Boolean
>   useOdbcRules, String& keyname, String& keyvalue)    bei
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey)    bei
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
>   Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)    bei
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionStringBuilder.set_ConnectionString(String
>   value)    bei
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder..ctor(String
>   connStr)    bei
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String
>   value)    bei MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection..ctor(String
>   connectionString)    bei
>   Quest.Toad.MySQL.MySQLConnection.CreateConnection()    bei
>   Quest.Toad.MySQL.MySQLConnection.DoBeforeConnect()    bei
>   Quest.Toad.Db.Connection.Connect(Boolean notify)    bei
>   Quest.Toad.Db.Provider.BackgroundConnector.CreateBackgroundConnection()

How do I avoid this error without having to change my password?
(on another account which doesn't use special chars in the password it's working)

UPDATE: i also tried to escape it with `\"` - but it leads to the same error.

UPDATE 2: i also tried to write the password in single quotes like for example `'Pass"word'` - also leads to the same error.

UPDATE 3: `"Pass\"word"` leads to the same error.

Comment: Did you manually escaping the quote character with a backslash?

Comment: Try as @WesleyMurch suggested: `Pass\"word`

Comment: i tried `\"` but it did not work out either.

Comment: Please try also adding quotes to the whole password: `"Pass\"word"` or `'Pass"word'`

Comment: @DanFromGermany thanks, but i tried them both and both lead to the same error unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Use `'` single quote around the password. So if password (for example) `jell"y` use it like

```
mysql -u root -p'jell"y'
```

Have Never used Toad but from [Toad's support page](http://www.toadworld.com/platforms/oracle/w/wiki/4023.sqlplus-set-escape-syntax.aspx) it says to use

```
SET ESCAPE ON
```

Then escape the special character using `\`

Not sure but it may help. So thought of posting.

Comment: I also tried this in `toad`'s password field - but it doesn't work either. Like @DanFromGermany already mentioned in his comments, it's not a programming question but an application question.

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't help me out either, because i can't use `SQL` options before i am connected to the database.

Comment: @northkildonan, did you tried looking around the Toad GUI too see if that option present or not. Just a guess.

Comment: yes i did. the only thing about escape characters i found was concerning parameters.

Comment: @northkildonan, In that case 2 options: 1. check with Toad support 2. change your password.